# Sub query for two tables base on status using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have two tables Patient and PatientStatusLog  using SQL tables

1.Patient

```
sno   patientid   status      createdby   Reegion
 1     481910      D             1222     India
 2     476795      D             1222     India
```

2.PatientStatusLog

```
sno     patientid   status           comments       createdby     CreatedDate(dd/mm/yyyy)
1       481910      A                mycommnet       1222         01/01/2000
2       481910      A                mycommnet       1222         02/01/2000      
3       481910      B                mycommnet       1222         01/01/2000
4       481910      C                mycommnet       1222         01/01/2000
```

I need output like below who have status A and createddate should recent pass date from  PatientStatusLog table using patientid of both tables

```
Region    status     CreatedDate
India      A         02/01/2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select . . .    -- whatever columns you want
from Patient p join
     (select psl.*,
             rank() over (partition by patientid order by createddate desc) as seqnum
      from PatientStatusLog psl
     ) psl
     on p.patientid = psl.patientid
where psl.seqnum = 1 and psl.status = 'A';
```

Note that this uses `rank()` because the creation date appears to have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    p.Region,
    psl.Status,
    psl.CreatedDate
FROM
    Patient [p]
    JOIN PatientStatusLog [psl] ON psl.patientid = p.patientid
        AND psl.status = 'A'
ORDER BY
    psl.CreatedDate DESC
```

For the subquery request:

```
SELECT
    p.Region,
    x.status,
    x.CreatedDate
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        PatientId,
        Status,
        CreatedDate
    FROM
        PatientStatusLog
    WHERE
        status = 'A'
    ORDER BY 
        CreatedDate DESC
) AS x
    JOIN Patient [p] ON p.PatientId = x.PatientId
```

Note that this is definitely not the best way to handle this, both from a code readability and optimization perspective.

Comment: i need using sub query i have other status to maintain in single row. @Wellerman

Comment: subquery from what? Sounds like your question is incomplete. Please add as much detail (sample data set, what you have tried, expected output vs output your code is giving, any error messages, etc.) so that I can give you an accurate answer.

Comment: can we achieve this using sub query second table should be sub query. @Wellerman

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan See my edited answer and let me know if that is what you are wanting.